# Scipy.optimize.minpack.leastsq with 2 dimensional args

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I am trying to calculate the 3x3 calibration matrix P of a camera based on 2D to 3D point correspondences as described in this paper http://cronos.rutgers.edu/~meer/TEACHTOO/PAPERS/zhang.pdf (section 2.3) using python 2.7. I have been able to find an initial estimate of P, but now need to refine it using the Levenberg-Marquardt Algorithm (2.3.4). It appears to me that this can be done with scipy.optimize.minpack.leastsq. However, my attemps at implementing this function have failed. Here is a simplified version of what I have (M is a numpy array of homogenized 3d points in the format (x,y,z,1) with a shape of (18,4) and m is a numpy array of homogenized 2d points in the format (u,v,1) with a shape of (18,3)):

```
import numpy as N
from scipy.optimize.minpack import leastsq

def e(P,M,m):
    a = P.dot(M.T) 
    print a.shape
    b = m.T-a
    b1 = b[0]
    b2 = b[1]
    b3 = b[2]
    dist = sqrt((b1**2)+(b2**2)+(b3**2))
    return dist



P = N.array( [ [4.66135353e+01,1.24341518e+02,-9.07923056e+00,9.59292826e+02],
               [-3.60062368e+01,3.56319152e+01,1.14245572e+02,2.32061401e-02],
               [-4.04188199e-02,4.00793699e-02,-9.48804649e-03,1.00000e+00] ] )

m = []
M = []
#define m list and M list
for i in range(0,len(uv)):        
    uv[i].append(1) #uv is unhomogenized uv coordinate list (source left out to      simplify)
    xyz[i].append(1) #xyz is unhomogenized xyz coordinate list (source left out to simplify)
    m.append(N.array( [ [uv[i][0]],[uv[i][1]],[uv[i][2]] ] ))    
m = N.array( uv )
M = N.array( xyz )
#the shape of m is (18,3) and the shape of M is (18,4)

P_new, success = leastsq(e, P, args=(M,m))
```

I think the problem is with the M and m variables, the arrays of vectors. I looked at an example for the scipy.optimize.lstsq function and I could get that to work but it had args with only one dimension.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I am fairly new to programming so take it easy on me if this is idiotic haha. Thanks so much to all who read this and let me know if I can provide anymore info

Comment: What did you mean by *have failed*? What error did it throw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `leastsq` doesn't know how to optimize multidimensional variables, a problem that is easy to work around:

```
def e2(P, M, m) :
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((m.T - np.dot(P.reshape(3,4), M.T))**2, axis=0))

P = P.reshape((12,))

P_new, success = leastsq(e2, P, args=(M, m))
```

This runs, although with my made up random data has trouble converging. The basic idea is to treat matrix `P` as a 12 item long vector, and reshape it inside the function when needed to convert `M` to `m`.

I have also taken the liberty of rewriting your `e` function in a more numpythonic way...

Comment: Wow, you are a champ! Thanks for the help! I'll be sure to thank you in my code too if I can get it all up and running